# How to toggle clicked menu link and untoggle all of toggled links

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website came with this javascript for submenu toggle that work, however, when I click a new menu link the rest toggled links does not close so all them are left open.

**How to toggle only clicked link and untoggle or remove all "open" links?** If you have a new format of javascript that's fine too.

jQuery(function($) {

```
$('li.has-submenu span.icon-caret').click(function(e){
    var $me = $(this);
    if($me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').hasClass('open')) {
        $me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').toggleClass('open');
    } else {
        $me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<div id="navMobile" class="nav mobile-nav">
<ul class="wsite-menu-default">
<li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
<a class="wsite-menu-item">Style</a>
<span class="icon-caret"></span>
<div class="wsite-menu-wrap" style="display:none">
<ul class="wsite-menu">
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
<a class="wsite-menu-item">Life</a>
<span class="icon-caret"></span>
<div class="wsite-menu-wrap" style="display:none">
<ul class="wsite-menu">
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
<a class="wsite-menu-item">Work</a>
<span class="icon-caret"></span>
<div class="wsite-menu-wrap" style="display:none">
<ul class="wsite-menu">
</ul>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML. Or rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the open class from each element first : `$('.open').removeClass('open');`

Answer (score 0):

First I would remove the `display: none` if you have no animations with jQuery on the menues. Further I don't know your CSS but you can try it like the following example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#navMobile .wsite-menu-item').on('click', toggleMenuLink);

  function toggleMenuLink(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).parent();

    event.preventDefault();
    target.siblings().removeClass('open');

    if (target.hasClass('has-submenu')) {
      target.toggleClass('open');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#navMobile .has-submenu > .wsite-menu-wrap,
#navMobile .has-submenu > .wsite-menu {
  display: none;
}

#navMobile .has-submenu.open > .wsite-menu-wrap,
#navMobile .has-submenu.open > .wsite-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navMobile" class="nav mobile-nav">
  <ul class="wsite-menu-default">
    <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
      <a class="wsite-menu-item">Style</a>
      <span class="icon-caret"></span>
      <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
        <ul class="wsite-menu">
          <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
            <a class="wsite-menu-item">New 1</a>
            <span class="icon-caret"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
      <a class="wsite-menu-item">Life</a>
      <span class="icon-caret"></span>
      <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
        <ul class="wsite-menu">
          <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
            <a class="wsite-menu-item">New 2</a>
            <span class="icon-caret"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
      <a class="wsite-menu-item">Work</a>
      <span class="icon-caret"></span>
      <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
        <ul class="wsite-menu">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately the jquery didn't work. The ajax link had stopped all animations on the site.

Comment: @Gretalia Please tell us all informations for your problem. Which ajax link and animations are you talking about?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
The jquery script didn't support the site as it stopped current javascript.

Comment: @Gretalia Do you run the code snippet? The link to the jquery file is just for this stackoverflow example. You do not need to insert this to your site if you already use jQuery there

Comment: Also the code starts with this 
jQuery(function($) {

Comment: These are the scripts that came with the site... <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

Comment: Yes the code snippet worked amazingly. Unfortunately the code didn't work on my site.

Comment: @Gretalia So you got the problems on your site and not with the scripts (for example the wrong script tags, multiple integrated jquery of different versions, and so on). You may create a minified fiddle which reproduces your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you can't do that we can't help you with your problem.

Comment: I revised the javascript and the code worked! Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I was able to crack the code...

```
$('li.has-submenu span.icon-caret').on('click', function(e) {
event.preventDefault();
    var $me = $(this);
    if ($me.parent().hasClass('open')) {
      $me.parent().removeClass('open');
      $me.find('.open').removeClass('open');
    }
    else {
      $('.open').removeClass('open');
      $me.parents('.has-submenu').children('.wsite-menu-wrap').addClass('open');
    }
});
```